# 90 degree phase shift

Tags: transistors, analog

I need to use a clock signal of 50% duty cycle of 2.5MHZ and I should make a circuit which phase shifts it to 90 degrees.

[image]

So now I have four signals...( **  PHASE SHIFT WITH RESPECTIVE CLOCK SIGNAL)

→ signal 3 ( 180 DEG  phase shifted) is just the inversion of the signal 1 ( 0 DEG  phase shifted)

→ signal 4 ( 90 DEG  phase shifted) is just the inversion of the signal 2 ( 90 DEG  phase shifted)

I could easily do with D flip flops, processors, but I'm interested in just using basic components (transistors, resistors, gates, etc.)

---

In the end, I solved it with flipflops. thank you everyone

Comment: *"i could easily do with d flip flops"* - are you sure about that?

Comment: yes Andy. using 2 d flip flops with a inverted clock for one, we get a 90 degree phase shift

Comment: At half the operating frequency!

Comment: yup!..... do you have idea how can i go about my circuit ?

Comment: Band-pass filter to make a sinewave. Precision full wave rectifier to make 5 MHz waveform then a fast comparator to make a 5 MHz square wave then, use flip flops.

Comment: A PLL could do that.

Comment: I'd love to see you do it with D-flip-flops because it would not be easy.

Comment: using 2 d flip flops with a inverted clock for one, we get a 90 degree phase shift but with 2 time frequency of the clock signal ..would do right?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: 5MHz **and** 2 D flip-flops with one having an inverted clock **is** the way to do it, but you said no D flip-flops.  All other methods would be a lot of work with out guaranteeing a 50% duty cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate fixed delays using R-C circuits and voltage comparators, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4GRLs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust R1 and/or C1 to get the delay you want, which is 100 ns in this case. R2 and R3 establish a switching point at exactly Vcc/2, which is important in order to get equal delays on the rising and falling edges.

Note that you can get a 1% resistor with the value of 143 Ω, but then the overall accuracy of your delay would depend on the precision of the capacitor.

Comment: This is a bad idea for a clock. You need to use hysteresis or the output will trigger multiple times, due to noise, causing metastability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this: a flip-flop or any other digital circuit needs an **event** (a signal changes state) to change the output. What are the "events" of your input clock? I only see the 0=>1 and 1=>0 events. Your outputs need an additional event "exactly in the middle" of the clock events. Is there a signal for that? So is what you want going to be possible with some flip-flops? If you can pull it off then please share because then I've been doing this wrong for the past 25 years!

With "only basic components" you can make a **poly phase filter** but that only works for sinusoidal signals. That's probably not what you're looking for.

You could generate the extra events you need by **frequency multiplying the clock** using a [Phase Locked Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop). You could make 10 MHz from the 2.5 MHz. Then deriving the wanted signals is easy using some frequency divider logic circuit. That will be **a lot more** than some "basic components".

Comment: yes Bimpelrekkie. I dont have any events although using 2 d flip flops with a inverted clock for one, we get a 90 degree phase shift, although with a half of frequency...and will use output of these two signals (which are 90 deg out of phase) for my use.......and you have any idea how i can i go about my circuit, anything idea possible?

Comment: the solution is simple 10M /2 twice D FF with inverted 5MHz for Clk 2 . there is no simpler way.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Assuming he has 5MHz.

Comment: With a  D and /2  you’re guaranteed to get with 10M in 5M out then 2 more D’ clocked with Q, !Q 5M to get /2 Quadrature out. So 3FF total

Answer (score 0):

Phase shifting a square wave by a fixed amount is equivalent to introducing an equivalent fixed group delay. Applying the Fourier properties to an input \$y(t)\$ yields

$$\mathcal{F}[y(t-\tau)] = e^{-j2\pi f\tau}Y(f).$$

Hence a time delay results in linear phase shift in the frequency domain. You can achieve this with a Bessel filter or any similar filter with a linear phase response.

[image: Bessel]

[source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter)

You may need to fiddle with the transfer function a bit to get the required group delay. Alternatively just use a PLL and preserve your sanity. There’s a reason they were invented.